# Grouped data model and nested foreach loops

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, foreach

I'm working on my first complex MVC project.  I have an existing database that I used Entity Framework 4.0 to model.  The project is basically a survey tool.  There are 8 tables in my viewmodel each with a few properties needed in my main survey view.  Those are basically questionaire, section, question, and possible answers (to be in the form of dropdownlists) plus the intermediate connecting tables.

```
public class MyQuestionModel
{
  public Questionaire Questionaire { get; set; }
  public QuestionaireSection QuestionaireSection { get; set; }
  public Section Section { get; set; }
  public SectionQuestion SectionQuestion { get; set; }
  public Question Question { get; set; }
  public QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }
  public QuestionAnswerListCode QuestionAnswerListCode { get; set; }
  public AnswerListCode AnswerListCode { get; set; }
}
```

My ViewMode MyQuestionModel is loaded like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var viewModel =
    from qa in db.Questionaires
    join qas in db.QuestionaireSections on qa.QuestionaireKey equals qas.QuestionaireKey
    join s in db.Sections on qas.SectionKey equals s.SectionKey
    join sq in db.SectionQuestions on s.SectionKey equals sq.SectionKey
    join q in db.Questions on sq.QuestionKey equals q.QuestionKey
    join qtc in db.QuestionTypes on q.QuestionTypeKey equals qtc.QuestionTypeKey
    join qddl in db.QuestionAnswerListCodes on q.QuestionKey equals qddl.QuestionKey
    join ddl in db.AnswerListCodes on qddl.AnswerListCodeKey equals ddl.AnswerListCodeKey
    where qa.QuestionaireName.Equals("TAD")
    select new MyQuestionModel
    {
      Questionaire = qa,
      QuestionaireSection = qas,
      Section = s,
      SectionQuestion = sq,
      Question = q,
      QuestionType = qtc,
      QuestionAnswerListCode = qddl,
      AnswerListCode = ddl
    };

  return View(viewModel);

  //var viewModel = new List<MyQuestionModel>();
  //return View(viewModel);

}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<MyQuestionModel> model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid )
  {
    // PROCESS THE POSTED DATA HERE

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyQuestion");
  }

  // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
  ModelState.AddModelError("", "error message");
  return View(model);
}
```

When constructing the view by iterating through the results using nested foreach and GroupBy and OrderBy Linq statements doesn't leave me with a model with results I can post back to the controller.  I tried using for loops instead of foreach but the grouping issues are causing me problems.  If I try loading the ViewModel discretely with out grouping and with just the distinct data for each table I end up with problems getting the correct types for each table and the composite ViewModel.  I would guess one of these 3 ways is workable but I'm not sure which way to hang my hat and grind through getting it to work.  I'm getting what I need [(See Image)](http://3pc.com/images/image.jpg) in the view using the nested foreach loops but I think I am breaking the model in the process as when I look at the posted model in the controller it is null.  Maybe my foreach statements are not constructed properly.  I can't help but think there is a more elagent way of doing this.  Ultimately I think using editor templates of other partial views may be best but I need to get a prototype working I can refine later.

```
@model IEnumerable<eValuate_Prototype_07.Models.MyQuestionModel>

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<table>  

  @foreach (var group in (Model.OrderBy(x => x.QuestionaireSection.DefaultSequence).GroupBy(item => item.Section.SectionName)))
  {
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">@group.Key</th>
    </tr>
    foreach (var item in group.OrderBy(x => x.SectionQuestion.DefaultSequence).GroupBy(subItem => subItem.Question.Question1).Distinct()) {
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>@item.Key</td>
      <td>
        <select id="ddlAnswerListCode"> 
          <option value="@Guid.Empty"></option>
          @foreach (var ans in item.OrderBy(x => x.QuestionAnswerListCode.DefaultSequence))
          {
            <option value="@ans.AnswerListCode.AnswerListCodeKey">@ans.AnswerListCode.AnswerListCodeName</option>
          }
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    }
  }
</table>
<p>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</p>  
}
```

My Questions: 
 Which is preferred foreach, for loop, or loading the view model discretely then use foreach?
 Is the way I'm using foreach breaking my model for posting?

Comment: `GroupBy and OrderBy Linq statements doesn't leave me with a model with results I can post back to the controller` makes no sense.  Additionally, I don't know what the model and method you are posting back to looks like (missing code).

Comment: This question also proves that you should always use meaningful names in linq.

Comment: @ErikPhilips what additional code would you like to see?  The model MyQuestionMode is the first code block.  The other models are individuals tables mapped by entity framework and used in MyQuestionModel.  The method I am posting to is incomplete as I have not done anything with the posted data yet as it's not posting correctly but the code is shown, see public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<MyQuestionModel> model).

Comment: @Magus please elaborate what names are not meaningful.

Comment: Why is a QuestionAnswerListCode a qddl? All of those could mean things, and therefore be clear. As it is, they seem to be abbreviations, which are bad enough normally and far worse when they make no obvious sense.